# Setting up a custom static image as splash screen with plymouth

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04

I am working on a project and I need to show a logo when the device is booting. The device in question is Ubuntu 18.04. I have tried *plymouth*, but for the love of god I cannot find a way to make it a static image. All I can find are ways to make it an animation from multiple images. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried an animation with 1 frame?